# How to increment "0000" and loop to "9999" using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new in vb.net and have searched for it but I am unable to find something for vb.net.

I wanted to increment "0000" until it reaches "9999" then loops until I get the desired output.

My plan was this:

```
if number = "0000" then 'result end if
if number = "0001" then 'result end if
```

But will take very long. I know there is a much better and shorter way to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Just keep it as an integer (starting as 0), which you can increment - then *format* that integer using:

```
Dim text = counter.ToString("0000")
```

And to make 9999 loop to 0000, you can just use this code to increment the counter:

```
counter = (counter + 1) Mod 10000
```

EDIT: If you *just* want to count without looping back from 9999 to 0000, you could just use a `For` loop. For example...

```
For counter = 0 To 9999
    Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString("0000"))
Next
```

Comment: @user2070986: Well I've given you both the "convert to string" and "increase then counter, looping from 9999 to 0000" part... what else would you need a sample of?

Comment: what will i keep as the integer? how do i implement it?

Comment: @user2070986: What do you mean? You just declare an `Integer` variable called `counter` with an initial value of 0. How much VB experience do you have? (If you're *very* very new to programming, I'd suggest that reading a book would be a better approach than asking questions on Stack Overflow. This site is great for helping with specific questions, but it's not a good place to learn a language from scratch.)

Comment: i want to start counting from "0000" to "9999" but when i tried your sample it starts counting from "0"

Comment: @user2070986: The *integer* starts from 0 (that's just a number) but I also provided you code to convert the number into a 4-digit string. Did you use that part of the code?

Comment: @user2070986 Dont worry about 0, you can turn 0 into "0000" like Jon said using counter.ToString("0000")

Answer (score 1):

Could `Enumerable.Range` be of any use to you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
  ' Generate a sequence of integers from 1 to 9999  
    Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9999)

    For Each num As Integer In numbers
        Console.WriteLine(num)
        ' or use this like Jon num.ToString("0000")
    Next
```

I mean this may not be that handy unless you want to go through the list of numbers at a later time in the code you've written. If you don't a simple for loop will suffice.

You could even generate the list of numbers in the format you require:

```
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).Select(Function(x) x= x.ToString("0000"))

For Each num As String In numbers
    If num = "0500" Then
       ' Do something
    End If
Next
```

Edit: As requested

```
Public Function IsValidNumber(Byval input As String) As Boolean ' Yes/No

  Dim numbers= Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).Select(Function(x) x= x.ToString("0000"))

  Return numbers.Contains(input)
  ' Which is the same as below
  'For Each num As String In numbers
  '    If num = input Then
  '      Return True
  '    End If
  'Next 

  'Return False

End Function

' Usage
Dim isCorrect1 = IsValidNumber("0567") ' Will return True or Yes
Dim isCorrect2 = IsValidNumber("10500") ' Will return False or No
```

Comment: Download LinqPad it is free and it will help you get your ideas working quicker. http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Hello, I saw your reply. My next question is how can i stop it each time it counts to check if it is the valid number then again continue counting until i reach the desired output?

Comment: See my edit. That is all I can offer you right now without writing your software for you :)